# Indentation of shorthands list

Tags: biblatex, indentation

A subdivision of my of my references is a `shorthands` list. In order to get it to look like the other subdivision, a regular `authoryear-ibid` bibliography, I've added this to the preamble:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shorthands}{%
  \usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}
   \finentry}
```

That works. Now the problem is that the bibliography is formatted with hanging indentation. I would like that for the `shorthands` list as well. I've tried with:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shorthands}{%
 \indent 
  \usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}
   \finentry}
```

... but instead of indenting the `shorthands` is makes weird dot between the blocks. How do I indent the `shorthands`?

**Edit:**
This is what my output looks like now:
[image]

I like how it is except I would like hanging indentation in the above `shorthands` list in the same style as below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The layout of the shorthand list is controlled by the `bibenvironment` in which it is set. This is usually the `shorthands` environment, which is designed to have prominent labels. To change this, you need to define an appropriate alternative environment.

For instance, if you define

```
\defbibenvironment{myshorthands}
{\list{\thefield{shorthand}}{%
  \itemsep\bibitemsep
  \parsep\bibparsep
  \labelwidth 0pt
  \labelsep 0pt
  \leftmargin\bibhang
  \itemindent-\bibhang
  \def\makelabel##1{\mkbibbold{##1}: }}}
{\endlist}
{\item}
```

And then print your list of shorthands with

```
\printshorthands[env=myshorthands]
```

You will get the following (I've shown the bibliography too so that you can compare them).

[image]

You should be able to fiddle with the list definition and label definition to adjust it more to your taste. I find it a bit of a black art, I'm afraid. There's a really useful account of how the standard list environment that is being used here operates in [this pdf paper from the Dutch TeX users' group](http://www.ntg.nl/maps/11/33.pdf).

I should say, however, that I don't think this is a terribly brilliant plan. With a list of abbreviations you really want to have the abbreviation immediately obvious, and I fear you are pursuing consistency at the price of convenience to your reader. But that's up to you.

Comment: @ Paul Stanley: That would seem like the way to do it. You might be right that is could make things a little complicated and might give me some other problems. If there's no easy solution I'll consider if it's worth the fiddling or I should stick with what i got.